# Cannot Load fontFamily:FontAwesome in reactnative

Tags: react-native

I'm build app running in react native metro builder but not running because font family font awesome not sync can help me

problem load is : console error : "fontFamily:FontAwesome" is not a system font in reactnative

Answer (score 0):

i am using the fontawesome 5.7.0

just add on your package dependencies:

```
"react-native-fontawesome": "^5.7.0",
```

re-install using yarn

```
yarn install
```

put the font files on folder

```
android > app > src > main > assets > fonts
```

files:

```
fontawesome-webfont.ttf
FontAwesome.otf
```

and you can use it on your project:

example:

```
import FontAwesome, { Icons } from 'react-native-fontawesome';
...
render() {
   return (
       <FontAwesome>{Icons.close}</FontAwesome>
   );
}
```